# How can I run SAP GUI with Python scripting?

Tags: python, sap-gui

Currently I'm working on how can I start SAP GUI Scripting with Python with the help of Stack Overflow but apparently my SAP GUI does not open the connection page the *Page where I enter USERNAME and PASSWORD*.

I believe `DCG210` is my connection name. Below is a picture to show where I land after I run the Python code:

[image: SAP Logon 740]

Also, I would appreciate if anyone have any links to learning SAP GUI Scripting with Python. Thank you!

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time


# This function will Login to SAP from the SAP Logon window

def saplogin():

    try:

        path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
        subprocess.Popen(path)
        time.sleep(10)

        SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
        if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return

        application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        connection = application.OpenConnection("DCG210", True)

        if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session = connection.Children(0)
        if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "USERNAME"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "PASSWORD"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])

    finally:
        session = None
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None


saplogin()
```

Comment: @wang How about this issue, already has any solution? I meet the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to log into SAP you can use this simple snippet and not enter password at all

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\\sapshcut.exe', '-system=DCG210', '-client=100', '-user=USERNAME', '-pw=PASSWORD'])
```

Your GUI script only logins to SAP and does nothing more, it is scripting just for scripting.

Comment: sorry I didn't find a file named sapshcut in the folder.